# how to update object inside object JSON using java and then send to request payload

Tags: java, json

I am reading a JSON object from file.

I am able to read the value but how can I update the code value for my payload

```
{
    "products": {
        "productsApp15": {
            "status": "active",
            "attribute_set": "Apparel",
            "name": "productsApp16",
            "product_type": "product",
            "code": "productsApp16"
        }
    }
}
```

Import I am using:-

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.json.JsonValue;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

My Code:-

```
// read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
            String firstName = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();

            System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName);
```

But this value is not changing my require data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is working for me:-

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

    JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
    String firstName = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();

    System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName);

    jsonObject2.remove("code");
    jsonObject2.put("code", "try");

    JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
    String firstName2 = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();
    System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName2);
```

Thanks to Rama Krishan

Comment: if it is working then accept it as answer @Shubham Jain

Comment: Yes I will .. I can't answer my own answer before 2 days .. Thanks Rama for your help

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
   JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
   String firstName = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();
```

Comment: cool .. it's working but how can I write/update on the same location? .. means I want to update the this value for my payload

Comment: I got it and I puts it the whole solution as a answer here .. Thanks :) .. vote up

Comment: ' public void replaceJson() throws JSONException
    {
        String json = "{\"products\": {\"productsApp15\": {\"status\": \"active\",\"attribute_set\": \"Apparel\", \"name\": \"productsApp16\", \"product_type\": \"product\",            \"code\": \"productsApp16\"        }    }}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
        jsonObject2.put("code", "try");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    }'

Answer (score 1):

public void replaceJson() throws JSONException
    {
        String json = "{\"products\": {\"productsApp15\": {\"status\": \"active\",\"attribute_set\": \"Apparel\", \"name\": \"productsApp16\", \"product_type\": \"product\",            \"code\": \"productsApp16\"        }    }}";

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
   JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
   JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)    jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
         jsonObject2.put("code", "try");
          System.out.println(jsonObject.toString()); 
}'
```